# How to suppress warnings in gromacs?

Tags: command-line

I'm working with gromacs and I encountered a fatal error as follows:

```
Fatal error:
Too many warnings (1).

If you are sure all warnings are harmless, use the -maxwarn option.
```

but when I try to add this option, it looks to be an invalid option.

How can I use this option?

Comment: Can you please show the exact command you are running and the exact output you are getting suggesting the option is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Just [read the fine manual](http://manual.gromacs.org/programs/gmx-grompp.html) carefully. It says:

> The `-maxwarn` option can be used to override warnings 
>   printed by gmx grompp that otherwise halt output. 
>   **In some cases, warnings are harmless, but usually they are not.
>   The user is advised to carefully interpret the output messages 
>   before attempting to bypass them with this option.**

and

> `-maxwarn <int> (0)`
>   Number of allowed warnings during input processing.
>   **Not for normal use and may generate unstable systems.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

`-maxwarn <int> (0)` means the `-maxwarn` switch needs the number of warnings to ignore and `0` is the default. So supply a number other than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error:
Too many warnings (2).
```

If you are sure all warnings are harmless, use the `-maxwarn` option.

I used this:

```
gmx grompp -f minim.mdp -c XXXX.pdb -p topol_XXX.top -o XXXX.tpr -maxwarn 3
```

It seems that the number of warnings would determine the integer to use as your `-maxwarn` option.